# Holomorphic function on unit disk with some inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Hi. This is what I've been trying to solve, but I couldn't.

I tried Roche's theorem, I got f' is never zero. But nothing more.

and then I tried Schwarz lemma (dividing both side by f'(0)) But Nothing more.

How can I solve this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Maximum Modulus Principle... By the way - author should explicitly state that $D$ is centered at the origin.

Comment: @luka5z
Thanks! You are right. D is centered at 0. So.. Use max. mod. principle to f'(z)?

Comment: Nick, I'll post an answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @luka5z thanks luka.

Comment: @luka5z ok, this question is marked, But I'm still wondering how can i solve this one by using max. mod. principle. Can you help me?